# What is the difference between photoelectric effect and Compton scattering?

Tags: electrons, photoelectric-effect

What is the difference between [photoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) and [Compton scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering)?
These two effects explains interaction of photon with electron. Why in photoelectric effect whole energy of photon is used up and in Compton photon gets reflected with some energy?

Comment: These are just two possible effects that play a role for low energy photons. With higher photon energy we would also be getting pair production. In case of the Compton effect the electron is quasi-free, while for the photoelectric effect it is bound to a nucleus or is part of a Fermi sea. Both effects have to satisfy energy, momentum and angular momentum conservation. Since the Compton effect deals with a two-particle system, it requires an outgoing photon to satisfy all conservation laws at the same time. In the three particle photoelectric effect an outgoing photon is not required.

Comment: Really helpful .